# Frequently used queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple update query as below which is frequently being used.

UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = ?, column_2 = ? WHERE id = ?;

The update query will execute every time when the customer is having a chat with support.

I have tried using indexes for two columns used in the query for reducing the time consumption.

I don't see much difference. Is it correct to use indexes here or is there any other approach to avoid the frequently use or time consuming.

Comment: The only index I can see which would be of any benefit here would be an index on the `id` column.  But, assuming `id` be the primary key of this table, it should already have a clustered index on it.  I don't see much way to further optimize here.

Comment: ok Thanks Tim for letting me know. It helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do to make this faster:

1. an index on `id`
2. **no** index on `column_1` and `column_2` and a `fillfactor` under 100 on the table

   Then you can get [HOT updates](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/), which are a considerable performance gain, since the indexes don't have to get updated.
3. use prepared statements to save on planning time